# LibGDX Using own libraries with android and desktop

Tags: java, libgdx

I programm with Java and LibGDX for Android and Desktop. I want to programm me a small wrapper/extension class for the LibGDX Application Listener, because I need Screen Handling(I know LibGDX has a own Game and Screen class, but there is drawing and update not splittet in two methods) and to split logic and drawing in two methods. I made a new Project in Eclipse, where I put all my extension classes. Than I referred all other projects to this project(Android, Desktop and Main Project). Now, if I start the desktop application, all works fine, but if I try to start the android project the app close at starting and I get a lot of error messages.

(I made a picture, too because this editor display it very confused, if someone know how to format this, I am happy if you write to me :)) 
http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3537/jwtv772k_png.htm
How I can fix this problems?

If someone want the errors as text:

> 02-18 20:05:21.285: W/dalvikvm(21979): Unable to resolve superclass of
>   Lcom/buschmannmichael/game/aliens/GameAliens; (1724) 02-18
>   20:05:21.295: W/dalvikvm(21979): Link of class
>   'Lcom/buschmannmichael/game/aliens/GameAliens;' failed 02-18
>   20:05:21.295: E/dalvikvm(21979): Could not find class
>   'com.buschmannmichael.game.aliens.GameAliens', referenced from method
>   com.buschmannmichael.game.aliens.MainActivity.onCreate 02-18
>   20:05:21.295: W/dalvikvm(21979): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance
>   1727 (Lcom/buschmannmichael/game/aliens/GameAliens;) in
>   Lcom/buschmannmichael/game/aliens/MainActivity; 02-18 20:05:21.295:
>   D/dalvikvm(21979): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x000b 02-18
>   20:05:21.295: W/dalvikvm(21979): Unable to resolve superclass of
>   Lcom/buschmannmichael/game/aliens/GameAliens; (1724) 02-18
>   20:05:21.295: W/dalvikvm(21979): Link of class
>   'Lcom/buschmannmichael/game/aliens/GameAliens;' failed 02-18
>   20:05:21.295: D/dalvikvm(21979): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call
>   0x4158 at 0x0d in
>   Lcom/buschmannmichael/game/aliens/MainActivity;.onCreate 02-18
>   20:05:21.295: D/dalvikvm(21979): Trying to load lib
>   /data/app-lib/com.buschmannmichael.game.aliens-2/libgdx.so 0x41e00010
>   02-18 20:05:21.295: D/dalvikvm(21979): Added shared lib
>   /data/app-lib/com.buschmannmichael.game.aliens-2/libgdx.so 0x41e00010
>   02-18 20:05:21.295: D/dalvikvm(21979): No JNI_OnLoad found in
>   /data/app-lib/com.buschmannmichael.game.aliens-2/libgdx.so 0x41e00010,
>   skipping init 02-18 20:05:21.305: D/AndroidRuntime(21979): Shutting
>   down VM 02-18 20:05:21.305: W/dalvikvm(21979): threadid=1: thread
>   exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41526ba8) 02-18 20:05:21.305:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(21979): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 02-18 20:05:21.305:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(21979): Process: com.buschmannmichael.game.aliens,
>   PID: 21979 02-18 20:05:21.305: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com.buschmannmichael.game.aliens.GameAliens 02-18 20:05:21.305:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(21979):  at
>   com.buschmannmichael.game.aliens.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
>   02-18 20:05:21.305: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):  at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 02-18
>   20:05:21.305: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>   02-18 20:05:21.305: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
>   02-18 20:05:21.305: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>   02-18 20:05:21.305: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 02-18
>   20:05:21.305: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>   02-18 20:05:21.305: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 02-18
>   20:05:21.305: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 02-18 20:05:21.305:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(21979):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 02-18
>   20:05:21.305: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 02-18
>   20:05:21.305: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 02-18 20:05:21.305:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(21979):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   02-18 20:05:21.305: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 02-18
>   20:05:21.305: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

The key lines of that error message are:

> 02-18 20:05:21.285: W/dalvikvm(21979): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/buschmannmichael/game/aliens/GameAliens; (1724)
>
> 02-18 20:05:21.295: W/dalvikvm(21979): Link of class 'Lcom/buschmannmichael/game/aliens/GameAliens;' failed
>
> 21979 02-18 20:05:21.305: E/AndroidRuntime(21979): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.buschmannmichael.game.aliens.GameAliens

In short, the class com.buschmannmichael.game.aliens.GameAliens extends a class (or implements an interface) which cannot be found at run-time. You should check your classpath to see why whatever it is you are extending isn't there.